# Java - How to have multiple subscribe from a single publisher in SpringCloud and RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

How to have multiple subscriber for a single publisher?

For eg. 
Two different message has been published to queue. Msg1 & Msg2.

Subscriber1 needs to consume msg1 and 
Subscriber2 needs to consume msg2.

How can we achieve this using spring cloud stream and rabbitMQ in java?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Event Routing feature](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_event_routing).
We support two models; *Routing TO* (specific message handler/subscriber) which is what you are looking for as well as *Routing FROM*. There are examples in the provided link so please go through it and feel free to follow up with more concrete question.